# Delete most recent files using Bash script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

How can we delete files for recent date. Let's say we have a directory : /usage/load and we want to delete only the files which are created today and keep all the older ones as it is.
what should be the command for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find /usage/load -type f -mtime -1 -delete
```

Find all files in the /usage/load directory that have been modified less than 1x24 hours ago and delete.

Comment: and what the command would be if i want to delete only last two days files that is today and yesterday files if i want to delete?

Comment: Would be 2x24 as opposed to 1 and so change -1 to -2

Comment: If the solution meets your needs, please take the time to up vote and accept the answer